# shopware 6 cart api out of memory

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have built an app that configures product bundles, the last action is to add the products to the cart. I make an API call to /store-api/context and then set the token as sw-context-key to make another call to /store-api/checkout/cart/line-item with the body:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id":"5a48801fa3164919b44bfc95bc5cf6831",
        "referenceId":"5a48801fa3164919b44bfc95bc5cf6831",
        "quantity":2,
        "type":"product"
    },
    {
        "id":"ed6149fc89834a7ebadde07c18509a4a1",
        "referenceId":"ed6149fc89834a7ebadde07c18509a4a1",
        "quantity":1,
        "type":"product"
    }
]
```

}

Unfortunately the response from the server is always an internsal server error with "Error: Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted".
What surprises me is that the memory_limit is set to 4096M according to phpinfo();.

The database product table includes 219000 entries.  Even if I set the memory_limit to 32768M it does not work, that is very strange. Maybe someone has found a solution for this of can give me a hint how I have to configure php right, so the api can work correctly.

Comment: Sounds like some bug / recursion. Are there any extensions active in the shop? Did you try to disable them and make the call? Did you try it with other products? Which exact Shopware version ore you using? Can you enable Xdebug which should show you a backtrace to give to some hints how to debug the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, there were a few tips that I have not yet tried. Thanks

Comment: Did you find out anything new?